# DynamoDB how to best perform != query?

Tags: nosql, aws, dynamodb

Within the **key-value**, hash-table DynamoDB we can only query for partition keys and optionally for a sorting key.

My Question is: If a Table **A** has items with *primary partition* attribute **aId** and I've been given a list of ids **[aId]**, which I want to exclude from my result, what would be the best way to retrieve N items of table A, which do not contain ids of my id list [aId]?